# Java - Different behaviour between exported JAR and Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

today I got a strange problem while trying to call a batch file from Eclipse IDE.

The setting for a normal user is:

- Call a .bat file
- This sets some environment variables
- And calls a Eclipse RCP application

The setting for my program is:

- Call the same .bat file via `Runtime.exec()`

When calling it as normal user, all works well, the RCP gets started.

When calling it within Eclipse IDE via `Runtime.exec()` I get an error message complaining that `Program Files\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll could not be found` (although it is there).

When exporting my program as an executable .jar file, it works well like I would click on the .bat myself.

What is the difference? (Operating system is Win7)

Comment: Verify your java build path in elipse

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse,

- Right click on the project and click "Properties".
- Select "Java Build Path".
- Select "Libraries" tab.
- Select "JRE System Library" and click "Edit".

Check if the System Library points to a valid JDK installation(not JRE). If it doesn't point to a valid JDK installation.

- Select "Alternate JRE" and click on "Installed JREs"
- Click on Add, point to valid JDK installation and click OK.
- In "Alternate JRE" drop down, select the newly added valid JDK and click Finish.

Run the program and check.

Comment: tried it with different installed jdks but no effect. Independent from the defined JDK it always complains about the missing jre6/server/jvm.dll ... it seems to be hidden in the RCP (unfortunately unchangeable). Therefore it's even more confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it.

It seems to be a specific problem of Eclipse 3.7.

After installing 4.2 all works perfectly well.